# Java multithreading and connection pooling with PreparedStatement

Tags: java, multithreading, prepared-statement, connection-pooling, c3p0

I currently have a Database class, with PreparedStatement member variables that are initialized in the constructor. Something like this:

```
public class Database
{
    private Connection connection;
    private PreparedStatement statement1, statement2, ...;

    public Database(String url, String user, String pass)
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

        statement1 = connection.prepareStatement("sql stuff");
        statement2 = connection.prepareStatement("sql stuff");
        // etc
    }

    public User getUser(int userId)
    {
        // execute getUser statement
    }
    // and other similar methods
}
```

The application will be multithreaded and I would like to use c3p0 for connection pooling. But I have no idea how to go about it.

Let's say I create a Database object for every thread, and the constructor now gets a connection from the pool. Each thread is supposed to only call one of the methods (with max 5 queries), then end. Will I have to initialize all the prepared statements every time? If yes, wouldn't it take too long?

Is there a better way I could do this?

Comment: I don't know if c3p0 supports statement caching, but there are pools that do. E.g., the [Tomcat JDBC pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementCache). With a pool like that you can re-use code that prepares statements. If a statement like it already was cached, the cached copy will be returned without incurring the cost of actually preparing the statement.

Comment: I just checked and c3p0 does have statement caching. Does this mean that if I prepare the statements in one connection, and another thread later gets another connection from the pool, the statements will be already prepared? Or will they have to be prepared for every connection in the pool once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the advantages of a connection pool is that it re-uses existing connections, something which your current implementation does not do. So the question "wouldn't it take too long to initialize all the prepared statements each time?" is not really relevant since creating a new database connection each time will most likely take much longer than initializing the prepared statements each time. Even if the prepared statements are initialized each time and never re-used, I doubt you will notice any performance difference because executing the database statements takes a much longer time than initializing prepared statements.

That being said, most JDBC drivers will have an option to cache prepared statements (i.e. this is not strictly up to the connection pool). See for example the MySQL configuration options [here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration) (`cachePrepStmts`, `prepStmtCacheSize` and `prepStmtCacheSqlLimit`). But please keep in mind that these optimizations are "nice to have", first and foremost make sure your program works correctly in the multi-threaded scenario (e.g. ensure you always return a connection borrowed from the pool to the pool, even when (runtime) exceptions occur) and is [maintainable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintainability).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Datasource which provides the way to pool the connection and then you application get the connection from pool.

You can create the datasource programmatic like [in this example](https://www.progress.com/jdbc/resources/tutorials/connection-pooling/creating-a-data-source) at the startup of application or you can configure from webserver console (depending on webserver) and then get the datasource in your app through JNDI

Precompilation and DB-side caching of the  Prepared Statement leads to overall faster execution and the ability to reuse the same SQL statement .

Comment: I think the question was about repeatedly incurring the cost of preparing a statement and how to avoid it. Not how to use the connection pool.

Comment: He asked `I would like to use c3p0 for connection pooling. But I have no idea how to go about it.` But i would clarify second part too also

Comment: Yes I know how to use the datasource. The problem is how to organize it  so it can be used by multiple threads and without taking too long with the statements.

Comment: @dluga Too long depends on how the database is destined to return data.